# Android: Anyone know what component this is (YouTube 'floating modal' component)

Tags: android, material-design

Does anyone know what component this is, and how one would go about implementing it? I have tried searching on material design docs for something, as well as a quick google search. This component appears on YouTube when you have a video playing whilst searching for another video. I would love to try implement something like this on my Android application. I have attached a picture of what appears to be a floating modal.

[image: The floating box just above the bottom bar]

Comment: You can replicate it by using MotionLayout.

Comment: See: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement this youtube like floating modal. you can use `MotionLayout`.

Please go through this tutorial to understand the concept:

https://medium.com/@Bytepace/animation-like-in-youtube-application-b811785ad31d

and the sample code as well:

https://github.com/BytePace/LikeYouTubeTransitionExample